# multi inner join in where exists invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query with multi joins [you can find it on sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d55e76/1) thats giving me invalid `DEF.ID`

How can I make the below join to read from DEFINITION table

```
SELECT * 
FROM DEFINITION DEF
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM EMPLOYEE E
              INNER JOIN MONTHLY_PAYMENT MP  ON (MP.ID = E.CODE)
              INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT DEP ON (DEP.ID = DEF.ID)
             )
```

Comment: It is working fine [Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=226ad3895cedf2836c6e1d96077cf6c4)

Comment: what exactly is the error? looks like you are missing the ID column in your DEF table

Comment: @lad2025 why in my sql fiddle is showing error ?

Comment: @DanielMarcus check the sql fiddle for the strucute and with its execution

Comment: MySQL does not support TSQL. If you tag TSQL you are probably using SQL Server/Sybase

Comment: Well does Def have an ID column.  You just had an almost identical questino.

Comment: @paparazzo i asked new because this query containes multi join

Comment: @lad2025 fixed the tags to be more precise

Comment: You need to relate `DEPARTMENT` to at least one of the other two tables it is inner joining with.

Comment: @Moudiz Even if it worked how does that multi join make any sense?  It is not correlated with the exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Oracles rules, there are two problems, first `DEPARTMENT` needs to be related to at least one of the the two tables it is being joined to.  And second, `DEF` cannot be used as a nested inner condition join and so must be used in the `WHERE` clause instead.

```
SELECT DEF.ID 
FROM DEFINITION DEF
WHERE EXISTS
(
 SELECT 1 FROM EMPLOYEE E
  INNER JOIN MONTHLY_PAYMENT MP  ON (MP.ID=E.CODE)
    INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT DEP ON  DEP.ID=E.DEP_ID 
    WHERE DEP.ID=DEF.ID
 )
```